# How to set multiple keys with the same value using Eloquent Model

Tags: php, laravel

I want to set some columns with `NULL`.

I want to do it only using the keys, like this:

```
$model->exampleFiller($myKeysArray, null)->save();
```

I'm currently using this:

```
$model->fill([
    'key1' => null,
    'key2' => null,
]);
```

I'm looking for a better way, do you have it?

ps: this is not something that will be used frequently, so I would not like to extend Eloquent Model. I just need a neat way to set it once.

Comment: So whats the problem. Write the `$model->exampleFiller()` method!

Comment: Yes, I can do that, I'm checking if somebody has a better idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found a way, if somebody found something better I will consider.

```
$model->fill(
    array_fill_keys($myKeysArray, null)
)->save();
```

> Opened this PR to fill this gap: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/14494

Comment: The key has to be fillable, see Model `protected $fillable`.

Answer (score 0):

Just finish your `exampleFiller` method:

```
...
public function exampleFiller($arr, $value)
{
    foreach ($arr as $prop) {
        if (property_exists($this, $prop)) {
            $this->$prop = $value;
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Might have to change some pieces because Eloquent doesn't actually set them as properties on the class, they are all stored in the `attributes` array`...   `if (array_key_exists($prop, $this->attributes)) { $this->attributes[$prop] = $value }